# XCode 6 on Yosemite crashing in fullscreen mode when build & running app on device

Tags: xcode, crash, macos

Xcode 6 on Yosemite crashes everytime when pressing Build&Run on Device.
Current window disappears and Start screen appears.
Anyone else experiencing this?

UPDATE:

As it seems Xcode is not crashing, but clicking "Run" triggers "close" and clicking "Stop" triggers "minimize". It's not whole buttons it's only area of closing and minimizing buttons behind.

[image: Corner in Fullscreenmode and fulscreenmode with controls displayed (when mouse over topbar)]

So concluson is that new fullscreenmode somehow sometimes shadows click to underlying controlbuttons.

Reported this to Apple.

UPDATE 23.4.2015

This seems to be fixed now in Yosemite 10.10.3 (14D131).

Comment: I can (unfortunatly) confirm this. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It's so frustrating not to be able to run the app connected to Xcode. Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @AbdullahUmer Not a real solution found yet. As primax79 mentoned  ⌘R works fine. And I have mastered to hit run buttons right edge so it doesn't trigger close action. Some eye hand coordination for everybody.

Comment: @saq I had found a solution. It turned out there's some kind of bug in the language settings. When I deleted Urdu language and restarted there were no more crashes :)

Comment: my workaround is to use the maximized window instead of fullscreen. you can maximize easily by clicking Option+(green button)

Answer (score 23):

It's not that it's crashing but it's executing the red close button when you hit the play button.  I have also seen it exit full screen when you press the stop button.

But Yes I have been seeing the same thing.

Comment: Yeah thats correct. It only closes curren window.

Comment: Good call. Looks like a Yosemite bug.

Comment: Considering how frustrated it made me, a pretty funny bug.

Comment: Unbeleivable it's been over a month and it still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: You have to mouse into the menubar, knocking the app into semi-full screen. Then the 'play' button works.

Answer (score 18):

I've started using ⌘R to compile & run the app, to avoid this problem

Comment: i tried using ⌘R but it still crashes. Any other idea?

Comment: This works every time for me. You saved my mac from being thrown out of the window...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same. Selecting file open>recent and then opening the file you already have open before hitting build&run seems to help.

Comment: not working for me :(